# If there is "onselectstart", is there "onselectend"?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

The JavaScript DOM Event `onselectstart` fires before the selection is changed. What if I wanted to get the new selection, check if this new selection `isCollapsed`? I'll explain a little further: the user selects content on the page, firing the *selectstart* event; but if one wanted to see what selection did the user select, the event would still pick the selection that existed before the user fired the event...(that might be more confusing..)

**Example scenario:**

```
<div id="content">Some filler paragraph</div>
```

And JS:

```
//content is handle for div#content
// I'm not worrying about cross-compat here (.attachEvent)...
content.addEventHandler("selectstart",function(){
   var nes=document.getSelection();
   if(nes.isCollapsed){
     // Do something
   }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `onselect` or `onselectionchange`?  You may not care about cross-browser compatibility but you haven't said what browser you're targeting.

Answer (score 4):

You may try handling the "mouseup" event and examining the current selection.